# Fallback to stdout if no file name provided

Tags: python, file, stdout

I have a script that accepts as an argument a filename than opens it and writes some stuff.

I use the `with` statement:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as out_file:
    ...
    out_file.write(...)
```

Now what if I want to write to `sys.stdout` if no `file_name` is provided?

Do I necessarily need to wrap all actions in a function and put a condition before?

```
if file_name is None:
    do_everything(sys.stdout)
else:
    with open(file_name, 'w') as out_file:
        do_everything(out_file)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def file_or_stdout(file_name):
    if file_name is None:
        yield sys.stdout
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as out_file:
            yield out_file
```

Then you can do

```
with file_or_stdout(file_name) as wfile:
    do_stuff_writing_to(wfile)
```

Comment: this seems a lot pythonic :) needs some `import` I guess

Comment: yes, sorry. Just added the `import` statement in my preferred way. Fell free to use it without `as` or `from`.

Answer (score 3):

How do you handle command line arguments? If you use `argparse` you could use the [`type`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type) and [`default`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#default) parameters of `add_argument` to handle this. For example, try something like the following:

```
import sys
import argparse

def main(argv=None):

    if argv is None:
        argv=sys.argv[1:]

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?',
        type=argparse.FileType('w'),
        default=sys.stdin)

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    print args.infile

    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

If a file name is present as an argument the the script argparse will automatically open and close this file and `args.infile` will be a handle to this file. Otherwise `args.infile` will simply be `sys.stdin`.

Comment: nice, didn't know about `argparse.FileType` +1 will it take care of closing the file too as with `with`? PS you could avoid all those sys.argc[1:]... :)

Comment: Yes you could. `sys.argv[1:]` is just used to remove the script name from the list of arguments, which is generally what you want to do.

Comment: `args = parser.parse_args()` is generally all I have to do, ;)

Comment: You're right: `parse_args` by default takes the argument string from `sys.argv`. I found a number of discussions of the pattern I use above but now can't remember why it is done like that! Anyway, perhaps it is all unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own context manager. I'll post sample code later if noone else does

Comment: ok but wouldn't be my workaround easier to read and understand? Anyway it's a nice point, +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if file_name is None:
    fd = sys.stdout
else:
    fd = open(file_name, 'w')

# write to fd

if fd != sys.stdout:
    fd.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `with ... as` construct is useful to close the file automatically. This means that using it with `sys.stdout`, as I guess you know, would **crash** your program, because it would attempt at closing the system stdout!

This means something like `with open(name, 'w') if name else sys.stdout as:` would not work.

This make me say there isn't any simple-nice way to write your snippet better... but there are probably better ways to think on how to construct such a code!

The main point to clarify is when you need to open (and, more importantly, close) the filehandler for `file_name`, when file_name exists.

Personally I would simply drop the `with .. as` and take care of opening the file - and, more importantly, close it! - somewhere else. Mileage for that might vary depending on how your software is working.

This means you can simply do:

```
out_file = open(file_name, 'w') if file_name else sys.stdout
```

and work with out_file throughout your program.

When you close, remember to check if it's a file or not :)

And have you thought about simply using the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module? That easily allows you to add different handlers, print to file, print to stdout...

Comment: thanks for tips but I'm writing to a `csv` using python module

Comment: @neurino well the rest of the answer still apply. Actually even using logging would still work ;-) might it might be overkill!

Comment: @neurino and wrt your comment to @paxdiablo answer, please read carefully what I wrote: your really cannot use `with` on `sys.stdout`, because you don't want it to be closed! That would crash your python program!

Comment: ...or indeed you rewrite your own `with`. But is it worth it?

Comment: I know but still my workaroud seems to me easier to read and takes care of file handling.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking for something smarter than my proposed workaround that does not use `sys.stdout` in a `with` statement. If solution is to drop `with` than I prefer my solution even if not that pythonic

Comment: I guess @glglgl will make you happy then :)